# Find data in matrix with a condition

Tags: python

From the following matrix:

```
ID Date Element  Data_Value
1  2009-04-29    56
6  2010-06-29    144
8  2007-12-14    -16
11 2008-05-29    28
12 2009-04-29    17
```

The first and last row in the list have the same date.
I want to make a list with the minimum `Data_Value` for a date. So `2009-04-29` should be `17`.

I have the following code:

```
start_date = date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2015, 1, 1)
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    date = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print(date)
    try:
        temp = df_TMIN['Data_Value'] == date.min()
        print(temp)
    except:
        pass
```

What do I do wrong?

Thank for the answer but it still does not work. Probably I give the wrong part of the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')
print(df[:15])
print(len(df))
df.groupby('Date').agg({'Data_Value':'min'}).reset_index()
df.drop(['ID', 'Element'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df[:15])
print(len(df))
```

The list is not changed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you'd like to retrieve the minimum `data_value` for each given `date_element`.

This can be achieved by using the `.groupby()` function on the DataFrame, then chaining the `.agg()` function and passing in the column you'd like to aggregate, along with the operation - as shown here:

Example code:

```
df.groupby('date_element').agg({'data_value': 'min'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  date_element  data_value
0   2007-12-14         -16
1   2008-05-29          28
2   2009-04-29          17
3   2010-06-29         144
```

Initial Setup:

This is irrelevant to the solution, just providing a reproducible example for you.

```
data = {'id': [1, 6, 8, 11, 12],
        'date_element' : ['2009-04-29', '2010-06-29',
                          '2007-12-14', '2008-05-29',
                          '2009-04-29'],
        'data_value': [56, 144, -16, 28, 17]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```